# Get hour with ctime (time library with ESP8266)

Tags: esp8266, wifi, time

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <time.h>

const char* ssid = "";
const char* password = "";
int timezone = 3;
int dst = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.setDebugOutput(true);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("\nConnecting to WiFi");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(1000);
  }
  configTime(timezone * 3600, dst * 0, "pool.ntp.org", "time.nist.gov");
  Serial.println("\nWaiting for time");
  while (!time(nullptr)) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(1000);
  }
  Serial.println("");
}

void loop() {
  time_t now = time(nullptr);
  Serial.println(ctime(&now));
  delay(1000);
}
```

This is my code, but it shows the time like this: Sun Jul 23 15:21:12 2017. But what I want it to do is to only show the current hour, not everything.
Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Use gmtime() or localtime() instead of ctime(). Print the hour field tm_hour in the struct tm.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Next time for aligning code, select code and press ctrl+k

Comment: @MikaelPatel I am a beginner at this, could you please give me an example of how it should look like?

Comment: @MikaelPatel Okay i tried this `Serial.println(gmtime(tm_hour));` but i get an error "'tm_hour' was not declared in this scope"

Comment: Here is an example of gmtime() and the struct tm; http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/gmtime/

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to use the standard function [localtime()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/localtime/) or [gmtime()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/gmtime/) and the [struct tm](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/tm/).

```
void loop() {
  time_t now;
  struct tm * timeinfo;
  time(&now);
  timeinfo = localtime(&now);  
  Serial.println(timeinfo->tm_hour);
  delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Nice example thank you.